# JQuery: Create HTML Elem/Content on Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla3.0

The following code runs perfectly fine as a standalone HTML on my production server:

```
<div id="mytest">
    basic content<br>
    <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#add').click(function(){
            $('#mytest').append('my new content');
        });
    });
</script>
```

However when I add that code snipet to a custom Joomla 3.0 module, it displays the button, but when I click it, I get the following in Chrome's console log:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null

Am I doing something wrong?  Is Joomla usurping my code somehow?  Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you including jQuery with the script tag you show here?  Take a look at: https://docs.joomla.org/Javascript_Frameworks

Answer (score 0):

You need to give it something to append to. The `.append()` function is being used incorrectly. Let me show you below or [SEE PEN HERE](http://codepen.io/illdapt/pen/GjjPmW):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add').click(function(){
        $('#mytest').append('my new content'); <------Doesn't Work
    });
});
</script>
```

Take a look at this example below:

```
var $newdiv1 = $( "<p id='new-item'>My new content</p>" ),
newdiv2 = document.createElement( "p" ),
existingdiv1 = document.getElementById( "#myTest" );

$( "body" ).append( $newdiv1, [ newdiv2, existingdiv1 ] );
```

Comment: Thank you for the examples and the codepen that I could see and play with.  However, the issue remains - although this code works stand-alone, it does not when inserted into my Joomla project.

Do you have any thoughts on why this might be?  I am getting the same error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null

The line in question is the newdiv2 which is a continuation of the variable declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to replace all $ with jQuery?
So, would have something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#add').click(function(){
        jQuery('#mytest').append('my new content');
    });
});
```